# Smoothly switching between dual-monitor mirroring and video output

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, video-streaming

I am currently building a little home studio and I want to achieve the following:

I have a Windows 7 machine hooked up to a DVI-Monitor and a HDMI-Monitor. Most of the times I want both screens to show the same output, but I want to be able to switch the image on the HDMI-screen to a looping video clip smoothly and via a hotkey while not changing the image on the DVI-Monitor.

Is there a solution to this or is this not achievable?

Edit: I am using an AMD HD 6870 Graphics card and want to play the video via VLC, but that isn't a given.

Comment: The basics of your question makes sense, but lacks details which someone might need to be able to give you an answer. If you [edit] you question to include the details about your display adapter (video card) and what software you are using to play the video, someone might be able to help you.